# Separate sessions once opening the same web page on two different tabs of the same browser Asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

Is it possible create Separate sessions once opening the same web page on two different tabs of the same browser

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="UseUri"></sessionState>
```

I don't want to display the URL like

```
http://localhost/SampleWeb/(S(afdg3ires1ik0lmjm3pkjtzl))/default.aspx
```

Answer (score 2):

That depends on your implementation -

1. If you are using the cookie session that the browser created itself and using this inside your application, then `NO`. It is not possible. Because this depends on the browser and the browsers usually use the same session, (which is saved in a cookie and only one cookie namespace exists for one site) for multiple tabs.
2. But if you are using cookieless session and using session key as `url` parameters, then this is possible. In this case you might have to implement or use your own custom session manager to manage sessions.

ASP.Net probably has a Cookieless session management system, but I haven't used that one before. You might wanna try that. You can find the documentation here -

[Cookieless Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx)

If you use cookieless session, then the session key is appended with the urls and thus you can consider different tabs as if they are different browser tabs, so this might work for you. Because in this scenario, there is no way the browser could identify both are same sites and should use the same session, as they are not using cookies.

Comment: But is it possible to hide the session name from URL for the cookieless session ?

Comment: You cannot hide it, because it is a query paramter, better you use Md5 hash or SHA hash or use a separate table only to store which user is associate with session then assign that session id and use it in url,  so that user who sees it does not get anything out of it.